# Sending data from node js server to React js component

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  
class FileList extends Component { 
 constructor(props) { 
  super(props); 
  this.state = { results: null }; 
 }  
 componentDidMount() { 
  const data = new FormData(); 
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/profile',{    method: 'POST',   body : data })   
  .then(     (response) => { 
  console.log("response");        
  console.log(response);         
  response.json().then((result)=>this.setState({ results: results }))      
 } // if the response is a JSON object   )
 .catch(   error => null // Handle the error response object )      }   
 render() {
  return (   <div className="Files">   
  <div>File content: {this.state.results}</div> 
 </div>   );   
 } 
} 
export default FileList;
```

still, there is the same issue no data is displaying in the component and there's a warning result is not defined.

Comment: when you console the response, are you getting it?

Comment: Are you trying to submit or fetch data to/from that URL/Endpoint?

Comment: app.post('/profile', (request, response) => {
    const postBody = request.body;
    console.log(postBody);
   
   let ln='/home/Documents;
  const directoryPath = path.join(ln, 'project1');
  
  fs.readdir(directoryPath, function (err, files) {
     
      if (err) {
          return console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
      } 
     
      files.forEach(function (file) {
          
    results.push(file);   
          
      });

var ss=JSON.stringify(results);
console.log(ss);
   response.send(ss);
  
     
  });
  
    
  });

Comment: this is my node js code

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to show `json` content in the react component.

For example:

```
<div>File content: {JSON.stringify(this.state.results)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this.setState` is out of scope.
Try the following:

```
  fetch('http://localhost:4000/profile', { method: 'POST', body : data })   
    .then( (response) => { 
      console.log("response");        
      console.log(response);
      let cmpt = this;        
      response.json().then((result) => cmpt.setState({ results: result }));      
    } // if the response is a JSON object   )
    .catch( error => null )
```

What this does is that store the scope of this in cmpt, and inside the `response.json().then(...)` when you use `cmpt` it has the correct scope.

A cleaner solution might be to write a separate function that parses the data and then hit `setState` from that function.

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/components/FileList.js
  Line 18:  'results' is not defined  no-undef
still there is the error.
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    const data = new FormData();

    fetch('http://localhost:4000/profile', { method: 'POST', body : data })   
    .then( (response) => { 
      console.log("response");        
      console.log(response);
      let cmpt = this;        
      response.json().then((result) => cmpt.setState({ results: results }));      
    }) // if the response is a JSON object   )
    .catch( error => null )
      
  }

Comment: @Joan try the following.
`response.json().then( (result) => cmpt.setState({results:result}) );`
then it should work out fine.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED what is this error?

Comment: can you verify if your node server is up?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting wrong results params to `this.setState({results:results})` it should be like this `this.setState({results:result})`that's why it is giving you "**warning : result is not defined**. Still it's not working then check your backend also.
Hope it helps for you..